# Inserting multiple key values from JSON into a database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm looking to insert data from a JSON post, which post a Question_ID and an Answer_Body. I'm able to insert a single answer per question currently, but I cannot produce the ability to insert two rows; such as two answers per question. My code currently:

```
    $answers = json_decode($_POST,true);

    if(isset($answers))
    {
        if(isset($form_id) && intval($form_id)>0)
        {
            $question_id = $answers['question_id'];
            $body = $answers['answer'];

                mysql_logging_query("INSERT INTO QuestionnaireFormAnswers
                                (`ans_form_id`, `ans_question_id`, `answer_body`) 
                                VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($form_id,$this->dbcon)."',
                                '".mysql_real_escape_string($question_id,$this->dbcon)."',
                                '".mysql_real_escape_string($body,$this->dbcon)."'
                                )",$this->dbcon);
        }
        else
            //error
    }
    else
        //error
```

Currently, this will insert into the table:

```
ans_form_id     ans_question_id     answer_body
    1                 3                 test
```

I want the ability to answer two or three times for the same question (like radio buttons), this would insert:

```
ans_form_id     ans_question_id     answer_body
    1                 3                 test
ans_form_id     ans_question_id     answer_body
    1                 3                 test2
```

Would I need to loop through the $answers['answer'] - I tried this (probably not correctly) and this wouldn't work.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What does your html look like? It seems `$answers['answer']` is a string and not an array, so looping over it will not work. And `$_POST` is an array, so using `json_decode()` on it will not do what you expect it to do either. What is the result of `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: Can you give us a peek in the json file. How are two answers for the same question delivered.

Comment: 3NF - Relational Databasesss

Comment: @Barry:  "question_id": "3","answer": "test"    - If I was to post another 'answer' key. It would only use that and not "test" as well.